# Radio Button layout in Grid

Tags: grid, radio-button

I have created a layout for a simple app which has one question and 4 answers in 4 radio buttons in a grid. I have designed the layout using 2 Radio groups. Please help me to design the same using one radio group. Thanks in advance[This is what my layout looks like, but I have accomplished this using two radio groups one after another using two radio buttons in each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqsCy.png)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.example.android.educationalapp.MainActivity">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Q1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/R1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Q1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/A1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/A1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/B1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/B1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/R2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/R1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/C1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/C1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/D1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/D1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/S1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/R2"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="Check" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/V1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/S1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    </View>


  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Q2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/R3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Q2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/A2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/A2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/B2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/B2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/R4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/R3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/C2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/C2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/D2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/D2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/S2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/R4"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Check"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckButtonClicked"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/V2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/S2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    </View>


 </RelativeLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

This is how my XML code looks like. All I want is that only one radio button should be selected at a time for each question. I know the code using one radio groups, but for two radio groups I'm unable to figure out. Please advice.

Comment: How about posting your code? It makes answer easier.

Comment: @Blackbam I have shared my XML code. Would appreciate if you can help me out.

Comment: Need help can anybody help me out please.

Answer (score -1):

The following approach works for me. It is based on the Udacity MOOC Material Design for Android Developers which contains a demo application named ImmersiveImages that has a group of nine radio buttons arranged in two columns. The code below is a simplified version of this app, generating a grid 1 row x 2 columns. It can easily be extended to a larger grid.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <GridLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CENTER"
            android:id="@+id/centerBtn"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FIT_END"
            android:id="@+id/fitEndBtn"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2" />

      </GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

  RadioButton centerBtn;
  RadioButton fitEndBtn;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    centerBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.centerBtn);
    fitEndBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fitEndBtn);

    centerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    fitEndBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    centerBtn.setChecked(true);

  }

  /**
   * Obtain reference to selected button
   * @param view The most recently clicked radio button.
   * @return The clicked radio button if different to parameter view.
   */
  public RadioButton getSelectedRadio(View view) {
    RadioButton[] btns = {centerBtn, fitEndBtn};
    for (RadioButton radioButton : btns) {
      if (radioButton.isChecked() && radioButton != view) {
        return radioButton;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

    // Determine if a radio button clicked and implement handler
    RadioButton checkedRadio = view instanceof RadioButton ? getSelectedRadio(view) : null;
    if (checkedRadio != null) {
      // Untick all buttons except currently selected.
      if (checkedRadio != view) {
        checkedRadio.setChecked(false);
      }
      String radioId = ((RadioButton) view).getText().toString();
      switch (radioId) {
        case "CENTER":
          Toast.makeText(this, "Button CENTER selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
        case "FIT_END":
          Toast.makeText(this, "Button FIT_END selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      }
    }
    else {
      // Other view handlers
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, the app is available to download from here:
 https://github.com/usplitu/android_grid_radio_buttons